# Запустить дочерний процесс не повлияв на родительский

Tags: php, многопоточность

Есть у меня скрипт, который должен запускаться по крону.

Коротко о скрипте: берет из моей БД значения и экспортирует их на другой сервер по средствам его API.
Суть в том что нельзя взять сразу все значения так как их очень много, нужно их постепенно экспортировать(ограничений API). Нужно брать их порциями по 50 штук.

Что я пытаюсь сделать: выборку 50 значений, экспорт по API, после этого таймаут 60 секунд, после этого запуск еще одного такого же процесса, закончить текущий процесс.

Проблема:

`exec('/usr/bin/wget -q --spider --tries=1 ' . $url);
die('Синхронизация продолжается в фоновом режиме.');`

Вот так я пытаюсь запустить еще один процесс. Но проблема в том что тот процесс из которого вызывается эта команда не прекращается, а ждет пока не закроется запущенный им процесс, а тот который запустился в свою очередь ждет тот который запустил он и так далее.

Comment: Чем плох бесконечный цикл с вызовом sleep(60) и break'ом при необходимости?

Comment: Вопрос не стоит в том как организовать экспорт. Вопрос в том как создать процесс и тут же о нем забыть и не ждать его выполнения.

Comment: У вас процесс-то не в фоновом режиме запускается, вот он и ждет, пока он закончится и вернет код ответа. Вам нужен символ `&` в конце команды (а, возможно, и не только он), чтобы процесс нормально запустился в фоновом режиме.

Comment: Уточняющие вопросы:
1) exec('/usr/bin/wget -q --spider --tries=1 ' . $url) - так вы запускаете ваш скрипт?
2) вы хотите запускать скрипт каждые 60 секунд?

Мои догадки/ответы:
1) запускать скрипт не wget-ом, а переписать скрипт для CLI и запускать скрипт как демон. Внутри цикл, условие - пока не обработаются данные. Для контроля работы скрипт - писать в отдельную таблицу информацию про ошибок и уже в админке показывать.

2) многопоточность вы не сможете реализовать из-за ограничений API стороннего сервера.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал заморачиваться с процессом, а сделал бы пул выборки и счётчик. По счётчику отбирал бы каждые 60 секунд нужный мне массив данных и передавал бы по API.

P.S.
Правда я не совсем понял что именно нужно передать данные или именно многопоточность организовать .

Comment: n = многопоточность - следовательно за единицу времени будет на n больше запросов к API. Если это сторонний сервис - то он всегда ограничивает количество запросов. Следовательно речи  многопоточности не идет.

Как я понял, он хочет запустить скрипт и забыть про него.

Answer (score 0):

я в пхп не силен, поэтому, как вариант могу предложить вариант на Си
парочка функций создает полностью независимый процесс:
fork();
exec();

Comment: Я тоже пробовал через exec, но начальный процесс через него ждет выполнения потомка.

Comment: Он тебе про сишные функции говорит, а не пхпшые. Они отличаются.
И более того - он не понял твой вопрос.